# GetProcAddress returns null value

Tags: c++, getprocaddress

I have this method exported from within a c++ project

```
#define EXTERN extern "C"
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)


EXTERN DLL_EXPORT unsigned int BattleManager::ProcessBattleInEntityProcess()   {
    ....
}
```

Using dumpbin i get the following mangled name for that method

```
?ProcessBattleInEntityProcess@BattleManager@Skill@Entity@@QAEHXZ
```

However, when i import the method in a .NET 4.5 project i get error 127

```
 nativeCallbackName = "?ProcessBattleInEntityProcess@BattleManager@Skill@Entity@@QAEHXZ";
 IntPtr _procAddress = NativeAPI.GetProcAddress(_nativeCallbackDLL, nativeCallbackName);
if (_procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     Console.WriteLine("NULL ADDRESS for {0}", nativeCallbackName);
     Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
     return;
 }
```

**This is just some extracted code, other methods work just fine.**

Comment: Do yourself a favor and export *undecorated* functions from DLLs (without name mangling).

Comment: The issue is your name -- it is either wrong or is not exported..  `GetProcAddress` is not lying and does not have bugs.

Comment: I know it's not lying, it's just that i copied the mangled name from dumpbin output

Comment: The [DllImport] declaration for GetProcAddress() might well be lying, it is an unusual function.  Anyhoo, you cannot call this function anyway since it is an instance method of a C++ class.  You don't have a good value for the *this* argument you must pass.  Use a C++/CLI project instead so you consume this C++ class directly.

Comment: That's part of a project that uses EasyHook, i know i can't call that method